# Spring repository filter by using an object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

So I'm making use of `PaginAndSortingRepository<>` in Spring. Now I have an object that is bound to this repository. Let's call it `AuditLogEntry`. So my becomes `PagingAndSortingRepository<AuditLogEntry, Long>`. I need to apply some filters to this repository, so I created a new model called `AuditLogEntryFilter`. This is not bound to the AuditLogEntry itself, but I want to use this object to filter out my `AuditLogEntry`'s. The first approach that I've came up with myself is make methods for each of the filter's properties that can be different. This becomes very complicated when the filter' size is expanding. The thing I want to do is this:

```
List<AuditLogEntry> filterByAuditLogEntryFilter(AuditLogEntryFilter filter);
```

Does anybody has an idea how to accomplish this? I already looked into make an implementation of the PagingAndSortingRepository, but then I have to implement all of the other methods. Which I don't want to do.

**Update solution:**

Thanks to @Nikolay Rusev, I come up with the following solution:

1. In my controller, I call my repository like this:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/auditentries", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String processFilter(final AuditLogEntryFilter filter, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap
           modelMap, Pageable pageable) {

   Page<AuditLogEntry> auditLogEntryPage = auditLogEntryRepository.findAll(auditLogEntryFilterSpec(filter), pageable);

   modelMap.addAttribute("filter", filter);

   return "audit";

   }
   ```
2. Then I made a spec with roughly the following code:

   ```
   public static Specification<AuditLogEntry> auditLogEntryFilterSpec(AuditLogEntryFilter filter) {
       return new Specification<AuditLogEntry>() {


           @Override
           public Predicate toPredicate(Root<AuditLogEntry> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

               List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<Predicate>();


               if(filter.getDateFrom() != null || filter.getDateTo() != null) {

                   if(filter.getDateFrom() != null && filter.getDateTo() == null)
                   {
                       Predicate auditLogEntryFromDatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(root.get("timestamp"), filter.getDateFrom());
                       predicateList.add(auditLogEntryFromDatePredicate);
                   }

                   if(filter.getDateFrom() == null && filter.getDateTo() != null) {
                       Predicate auditLogEntryToDatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.lessThan(root.get("timestamp"), filter.getDateTo());
                       predicateList.add(auditLogEntryToDatePredicate);
                   }

                   if(filter.getDateFrom() != null && filter.getDateTo() != null) {
                       Predicate auditLogEntryFromDatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(root.get("timestamp"), filter.getDateFrom());
                       Predicate auditLogEntryToDatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.lessThan(root.get("timestamp"), filter.getDateTo());
                       predicateList.add(auditLogEntryFromDatePredicate);
                       predicateList.add(auditLogEntryToDatePredicate);
                   }

               }

               Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[predicateList.size()];
               predicateList.toArray(predicates);

               return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates);
           }
       };
   }
   ```

Now it retrieves the right results according to the filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you need to look at spring data specifications. here is the spring documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#specifications

here is a good articles about it:

http://info.michael-simons.eu/2014/09/24/creating-specification-instances-for-spring-data-jpa-with-spring-mvc/

http://blog.kaczmarzyk.net/2014/03/23/alternative-api-for-filtering-data-with-spring-mvc-and-spring-data/

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. Now looking into the data specifications. Once I succeed, I will update my answer.

Comment: @Nikolay Rusev Useful links..!